# OpenGL: Bezier surface with triangulation

Tags: c++, opengl

I tried to draw Bezier surface using OpenGL. My program reads an input file with number of sample points for plot, control points and color palette for surface coloring. It must output a new window with surface plot where I can manipulate properties of surface and control points.

Points generated from Bernstein polynomial are triangulated and assigned a color by color palette by mapping it from minimum and maximum height of triangles.

When I execute it, one row of triangles is assigned with a wrong color. I thought that I have an error in one of my loops but changing values proved nothing.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;


struct vertex
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};


struct RGB
{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};


int main_window;


bool TM = true;
vertex surfaceTranslate;
float surfaceRotate = 0;
vertex camera;
vertex up;
int currentPointX = 0, currentPointY = 0;
vertex toY;

int SampleR, SampleC;
int M, N;
int K;
vector < vector <vertex> > points;
vector <RGB> palette;
vector < vector <vertex> > control;
float minH, maxH;


int fact (int n)
{
    if (!n || n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * fact (n - 1);
}

int C (int n, int i)
{
    return fact (n) / (fact (i) * fact (n - i));
}


void initialDisplay(void)
{
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glDisable (GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable (GL_RESCALE_NORMAL);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective (60, 1, 1, 1000000);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}


void updateControl()
{
    control.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < SampleR; ++i)
    {
        vector <vertex> temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < SampleC; ++j)
        {
            float u = (float)(i) / (SampleR - 1);
            float v = (float)(j) / (SampleC - 1);
            vertex p;
            p.x = p.y = p.z = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < M; ++k)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < N; ++m)
                {
                    float B_u = C (M - 1, k) * pow (u, k) * pow (1 - u, M - 1 - k);
                    float B_v = C (N - 1, m) * pow (v, m) * pow (1 - v, N - 1 - m);
                    p.x += B_u * B_v * points[k][m].x;
                    p.y += B_u * B_v * points[k][m].y;
                    p.z += B_u * B_v * points[k][m].z;
                }
            }
            temp.push_back (p);
        }
        control.push_back (temp);
    }
    maxH = 1 << ((sizeof(float) * 8) - 1);
    minH = -maxH;
    for (int i = 0; i < SampleR - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SampleC - 1; ++j)
        {
            float h = (control[i][j].y + control[i + 1][j].y + control[i][j + 1].y) / 3;
            if (h > maxH)
            {
                maxH = h;
            }
            if (h < minH)
            {
                minH = h;
            }
            h = (control[i + 1][j].y + control[i][j + 1].y + control[i + 1][j + 1].y) / 3;
            if (h > maxH)
            {
                maxH = h;
            }
            if (h < minH)
            {
                minH = h;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SampleR; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SampleC; ++j)
        {
            toY.x += control[i][j].x;
            toY.z += control[i][j].z;
        }
        toY.x /= SampleR * SampleC;
        toY.z /= SampleR * SampleC;
    }
}


void display(void)
{
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt (camera.x, camera.y, camera.z, 0, 0, 0, up.x, up.y, up.z);
    glTranslatef (surfaceTranslate.x, surfaceTranslate.y, surfaceTranslate.z);
    glTranslatef (toY.x, toY.y, toY.z);
    glRotatef (surfaceRotate, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef (- toY.x, -toY.y, -toY.z);
    if (!TM)
    {
        glPointSize (10);
        glBegin (GL_POINTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            {
                if (i == currentPointX && j == currentPointY)
                {
                    glColor3f (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
                }
                else
                {
                    glColor3f (0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                }
                glVertex3f (points[i][j].x, points[i][j].y, points[i][j].z);
            }
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (int i = 0; i < SampleR - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SampleC - 1; ++j)
        {
            glVertex3f (control[i][j].x, control[i][j].y, control[i][j].z);
            glVertex3f (control[i + 1][j].x, control[i + 1][j].y, control[i + 1][j].z);
            glVertex3f (control[i][j + 1].x, control[i][j + 1].y, control[i][j + 1].z);
            float h = (control[i][j].y + control[i + 1][j].y + control[i][j + 1].y) / 3;
            int index = K * (h - minH) / (maxH - minH);
            glColor3f (palette[index].r / 255, palette[index].g / 255, palette[index].b / 255);
            glVertex3f (control[i + 1][j].x, control[i + 1][j].y, control[i + 1][j].z);
            glVertex3f (control[i][j + 1].x, control[i][j + 1].y, control[i][j + 1].z);
            glVertex3f (control[i + 1][j + 1].x, control[i + 1][j + 1].y, control[i + 1][j + 1].z);
            h = (control[i + 1][j].y + control[i][j + 1].y + control[i + 1][j + 1].y) / 3;
            index = K * (h - minH) / (maxH - minH);
            glColor3f (palette[index].r / 255, palette[index].g / 255, palette[index].b / 255);
        }
    }
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void keyboardEvent (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (TM)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case ('2'):
                TM = false;
                glutSetWindowTitle ("Surface Editing Mode");
                break;
            case ('q'):
                --surfaceTranslate.x;
                break;
            case ('w'):
                ++surfaceTranslate.x;
                break;
            case ('a'):
                --surfaceTranslate.y;
                break;
            case ('s'):
                ++surfaceTranslate.y;
                break;
            case ('z'):
                --surfaceTranslate.z;
                break;
            case ('x'):
                ++surfaceTranslate.z;
                break;
            case ('r'):
                ++surfaceRotate;
                break;
            case ('t'):
                --surfaceRotate;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case ('1'):
                TM = true;
                glutSetWindowTitle ("Transformation Mode");
                break;
            case ('q'):
                --points[currentPointX][currentPointY].x;
                updateControl();
                break;
            case ('w'):
                ++points[currentPointX][currentPointY].x;
                updateControl();
                break;
            case ('a'):
                --points[currentPointX][currentPointY].y;
                updateControl();
                break;
            case ('s'):
                ++points[currentPointX][currentPointY].y;
                updateControl();
                break;
            case ('z'):
                --points[currentPointX][currentPointY].z;
                updateControl();
                break;
            case ('x'):
                ++points[currentPointX][currentPointY].z;
                updateControl();
                break;
            case ('i'):
                if (!(SampleR % 2))
                {
                    SampleR /= 2;
                    updateControl();
                }
                break;
            case ('o'):
                SampleR *= 2;
                updateControl();
                break;
            case ('k'):
                if (!(SampleC % 2))
                {
                    SampleC /= 2;
                    updateControl();
                }
                break;
            case ('l'):
                SampleC *= 2;
                updateControl();
                break;
        }
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void arrowKeys (int key, int x, int y)
{
    if (!TM)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case (GLUT_KEY_UP):
                if (currentPointY < N - 1)
                {
                    ++currentPointY;
                }
                break;
            case (GLUT_KEY_DOWN):
                if (currentPointY)
                {
                    --currentPointY;
                }
                break;
            case (GLUT_KEY_LEFT):
                if (currentPointX)
                {
                    --currentPointX;
                }
                break;
            case (GLUT_KEY_RIGHT):
                if (currentPointX < M - 1)
                {
                    ++currentPointX;
                }
                break;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}


void changeDirection (int x, int y)
{
    float dist = sqrt (pow (camera.x, 2) + pow (camera.y, 2) + pow (camera.z, 2));
    camera.x = dist * sin (360.0 / 800 * x * 0.0174532) * sin (360.0 / 800 * y * 0.0174532);
    camera.y = dist * cos (360.0 / 800 * y * 0.0174532);
    camera.z = dist * cos (360.0 / 800 * x * 0.0174532) * sin (360.0 / 800 * y * 0.0174532);
    up.x = dist * sin (360.0 / 800 * x * 0.0174532) * sin (360.0 / 800 * y * 0.0174532 - 1) - camera.x;
    up.y = dist * cos (360.0 / 800 * y * 0.0174532 - 1) - camera.y;
    up.z = dist * cos (360.0 / 800 * x * 0.0174532) * sin (360.0 / 800 * y * 0.0174532 - 1) - camera.z;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void mouseEvent (int key, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        changeDirection (x, y);
    }
}



void readFile (char *fname)
{
    ifstream file (fname);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file >> SampleR >> SampleC;
        file >> M >> N;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        {
            vector <vertex> tempv;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            {
                vertex temp;
                file >> temp.x >> temp.y >> temp.z;
                tempv.push_back (temp);
            }
            points.push_back (tempv);
        }
        file >> K;
        for (int i = 0; i < K; ++i)
        {
            RGB temp;
            file >> temp.r >> temp.g >> temp.b;
            palette.push_back (temp);
        }
    }
    file.close();
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    surfaceTranslate.x = surfaceTranslate.y = surfaceTranslate.z = toY.x = toY.y = toY.z = up.x = up.z = 0;
    up.y = 1;
    camera.x = camera.y = camera.z = 100;
    readFile (argv[1]);
    updateControl();
    glutInit (&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition (50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize (800, 800);
    main_window = glutCreateWindow ("Transformation Mode");
    glutDisplayFunc (display);
    glutKeyboardFunc (keyboardEvent);
    glutSpecialFunc (arrowKeys);
    glutMouseFunc (mouseEvent);
    glutMotionFunc (changeDirection);
    initialDisplay();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are problematic in display():

- glColor3f should be called before the calls to glVertex3f to color them
- your palette index calculation is wrong when h == maxH, it makes an out of bounds access

When h == maxH, (h - minH)/(maxH - minH) equals 1.0f, which means the line:

```
index = K * (h - minH) / (maxH - minH);
```

simplifies into:

```
index = K;
```

and K is the size of the palette. An easy fix would be to add a call to min(), like that:

```
index = min(K-1, K * (h - minH) / (maxH - minH));
```